# Removing <br> using XmlPullParser Android

Tags: android, html, tags, xmlpullparser

Here is the xml code.

```
<menunm1>675Kcal<br>Sausage<br>HashBrown<br>Ketchup</menunm1>
```

This is the android code using xmlpullparser. I would like to remove br tag.
Anyone can help this out? thank you

```
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

if (tag.equals("menunm1") && !xpp.getText().contains("\n")) {
                                    menunm1 = xpp.getText();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
else if (tag.equals("menunm1") && !xpp.getText().contains("\n")) {

                                    menunm1 = xpp.getText();
                                    menunm1 = menunm1.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles here from google, this is a much more thorough solution I came up with

```Java
else if (tag.equals("menunm1") && !xpp.getText().contains("\n")) {
    menunm1 = xpp.getText();
    menunm1 = menunm1.replaceAll("\\<\s*br\s*/?\s*>","\n");
}
```

This will catch not only <br>, but also <br/>, <br />, <   br  / > etc.